# Error firing in my simple Google App Engine test

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to retrieve a list of saved Message objects stored in the DataStore. I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp__init__.py",
>   line 515, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)   File "C:\Users\Sergio\Downloads\python-test\python-test\gae_test\handlers.py",
>   line 23, in get
>       messages = data.get_messages()   File
>   "C:\Users\Sergio\Downloads\python-test\python-test\gae_test\data.py",
>   line 12, in get_messages
>       dbMessage = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message ORDER BY author DESC")
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py",
>   line 2296, in **init**
>       model_class = class_for_kind(self._proto_query._entity)
>   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py",
>   line 266, in class_for_kind
>       raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind) KindError: No
>   implementation for kind 'Message'

Maybe someone with experience can explain what that exception means exactly.

Here's my code:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    messages = data.get_messages()
    return self.render('index.html', messages=messages)

#This is in data.py
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Message(object):
  def __init__(self, body, author, email, phone):
    self.body = body
    self.author = author
    self.email = email
    self.phone = phone

def get_messages():
  #TODO: Implement
  dbMessage = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message ORDER BY author DESC")

  messages =  []  
  for message in dbMessages:
    messages.append(message)

  return messages

  #return [
  #  Message('Hey, how are you doing?', 'Joel Hodgson', 'joel@hogson.com', '847-555-1020'),
  #  Message('Hey there! Love the website.', 'Brian Gordy', 'bg@gordoindustries.com', None),
  #  Message('What is this?', 'Linda Bleeker', None, '415-555-5555'),
  #]

#This is in Index.html:

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Messages{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Leave a new message</h2>
  {% include "create.html" %}

  <h2>Existing Messages</h2>
  <div id="list">
    {% include "list.html" %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

#And this in list.html

<ul id="messages">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <li>
    {{ message.author }}: "{{ message.body }}"
    <span class="contact-info">{{ message.phone }} &bull; {{ message.email }}</span>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Post a self-contained slice of code, so we can copy, paste and debug?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing an import.

For a gql query to execute, you have to import the actual models it references.

Comment: I have all the necessary imports, but still no dice. Any other suggestions?

Comment: is there a Message Class with the Properties of author body , etc??

Comment: The only other thing I can think of from what you have given is a naming conflict of some sort; appengine behaves a bit unexpectedly with that sometimes.  I'd try renaming the class to something more specific, or moving it or something.

Other than that, you'd have to do what TryPyPy said and post a self-contained snippet if you want more help.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the model class - in this case, 'Message' - hasn't been loaded when you execute the query. I don't see it anywhere in the snippet you pasted - make sure it's included, and is imported before you execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

i dont see the Message Class which represents the Message's elements

insert this and if its inserted already please notify me

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

class Message(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    body= db.StringProperty()
    phone= db.StringProperty()
    email = db.StringProperty()

and offcourse there should messages in the DataStore to retrieve

so you should insert messages using the put Method for example in this scenario in the post method

```
message = Message()
message.author = "the author"
message.body = "the body"
message.phone ="phone number"
message.email = "email"
message.put()
```

Comment: i'm still not seeing the code for inserting it in the datastore , you are just creating a class

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Message class does not extend db.Model or ndb.Model.

Also, and this is a matter of taste, I'd prefer to have Message.query() to get all objects of type Message rather than a GQL query.

Check the test code for a library I wrote:

The model definition is at: https://github.com/rbanffy/appengine-fixture-loader/blob/master/tests/multi_level_tests.py#L15-L34

And the "SELECT * FROM Person" equivalent: https://github.com/rbanffy/appengine-fixture-loader/blob/master/tests/multi_level_tests.py#L56